# My view display raw data instead of showing the data in Datatables

Tags: python, django, ajax, datatables

I have been trying to understand how ajax and Datatables works in Django. But, as the title says, my list of data is being raw displayed in my view.

Screenshot:
[image]

I will put here my code so you can help me understand what's missing, or wrong.

My list view:

```
class SampleList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Samples
    
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        data = list(self.get_queryset().values())
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Samples List{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="main-panel">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- partial -->
        <h2>Here are all samples: </h2>
        <h1>Samples</h1>
        <table id="samples-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
//I don't know if here must be empty
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Initialize DataTable
                $('#samples-table').DataTable({
                    // Replace "yourmodel-list/" with the URL of your view
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "{% url 'samples:samplelist' %}",
                        "dataSrc": "data" // Property name that holds the array of records in the JSON response
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {"data": "id"},  // Column for ID
                        {"data": "sample_code"},  // Column for Name
                        {"data": "reception_date"},  // Column for Date
                    ],
                });
            });
        </script>

        {% comment %} <div>
            <ul>
                {% for sample in object_list %}
                <li>{{ sample.sample_code }} | <a 
                    href="{% url 'samples:sample-update' sample.pk %}">edit</a>
                <a href="{% url 'samples:sample-delete' sample.pk %}">delete</a>
                </li>
            {% empty %}
            <li>No samples yet.</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'samples:sample-add' %}">add a sample</a>
        </p>
        </div> {% endcomment %}
    </div>
    <!-- main panel ends here-->
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

and jquery libraries:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Can you help me understanding how this works? Thank you.

It should automatically display the data in my datatables because of ajax getting the data from my view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you rendered a JSONResponse.
You shall return your template by

```
return render(request, template_name, context={"data":data})
```